# Why do documents in the iCloud window appear disabled?

Tags: icloud

Here’s how documents appear in the iCloud window of one of my apps:

[image: Disabled documents]

I have created these documents before. They looked OK. When I quit the app and come back, they look like this, disabled, and apparently no way to open them. I can create a new document, but it will appear all the same. When I save a document with the same name as these to overwrite them, it will appear all the same.

Why are these documents disabled, and can I do anything myself to fix it?

Comment: What do you see if you go to `~/Library/Mobile Documents/<Calca-bundle-ID>`?

Comment: I see the two Markdown documents existing as actual files, with the correct content.